# Вставить в JSON переменную как имя атрибута

Tags: javascript, node.js

Нужно создать элемент в JSON из двух переменных - логин и пароль. Но при выполнении строчки `json.login = password` создается элемент не с именем переменной, а с именем "login".

Как можно вставить переменную как имя элемента?

Код:

```
const express = require("express");
const jsSHA = require("jssha");
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));



app.get("/auth", function(request, response){
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/templates/auth/index.html");
});

app.get("/api/auth/login", function(request, response){
  const login = request.query.login;
  const password = request.query.pass;
  var jsonFile = fs.readFile("accounts.json", "utf8", function(err, data){
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
    json.login = password;
    var jsonnn = JSON.stringify(json);
    fs.writeFile("accounts.json", jsonnn, function(err, result){
      if(err){
        console.log("error");
      }
    });
  });



});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Используйте нотацию в квадратных скобках: `json[login] = password;`.

Comment: См. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 1):

#### [Инициализация объектов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```js
const fakeRequest = {
  query: { login: 'fake', pass: 'fake1' }
};
const fakeAccountsFileData = {
  a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'z'
};

const login = fakeRequest.query.login;
const password = fakeRequest.query.pass;

// Удобный способ
console.log({
  ...fakeAccountsFileData,
  [login]: password
});

// Классический способ
fakeAccountsFileData[login] = password;
console.log(fakeAccountsFileData);
```

Ваш код с нормальной обработкой:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const jsSHA = require("jssha");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/auth', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/templates/auth/index.html');
});

// тут должен быть .post
app.get('/api/auth/login', function(request, response) {
  const login = request.query.login;
  let password = request.query.pass;

  fs.readFile('accounts.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      response.status(500).send('SOMETHING_WRONG');
    }

    const accountsJson = JSON.parse(data);
    accountsJson[login] = password; // hash password here

    fs.writeFile(
      'accounts.json',
      JSON.stringify(accountsJson),
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          response.status(500).send('SOMETHING_WRONG');
        }

        res.json({ ok: true });
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```